# Create log file of specific size using interceptor in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How can we set the file size for logs generated by interceptors in Entity Framework?

```
<interceptor type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DatabaseLogger, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
        <parameter value="LogOutput.txt"/>
        <parameter value="true" type="System.Boolean"/>
    </parameters>
</interceptor>
```

I want to create the log file of specified size and when that size reaches it starts creating the another log file. Instead of keep writing the log in the same file

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, because DatabaseLogger class just don't have such option. But, this class is VERY simple, here is it's source code: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Infrastructure/Interception/DatabaseLogger.cs

When loaded, it just uses DatabaseLogFormatter capabilities, just writing whatever formatter provides to a single file. You can implement your own interceptor doing the same, but log to a different files. You can even just use already existing solutions like log4net to do this for you. Then in your interceptor you just log to log4net and it will manage files for you.